# Azure DevOps classic CI pipelines : are checkouts implicit?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was noticing that while in yaml pipeline you can do an explicit checkout in classic pipelines I never saw an explicit checkout. Is it correct or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you are correct if you don't want to checkout code you need to mark `Don't sync sources`

[image]

and then

[image]

Comment: What I wanted to say is that it seems to me that using classing CI pipelines checkout cannot be avoided if you don't need it. I might be wrong however, maybe there is an option to avoid it.

Comment: I'm wrong, if you disable code sync checkout is not done also in classic ci pipelines

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. I misunderstood you. Sorry for that. I changed my reply so it reflects what you were asking about.